# How do i mock _asdict() method for sqlalchemy row in Pytest and MagicMock?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

Below is my actual code

```
    results = session.execute(query)
    for row in results:
        final.append(row._asdict())
    return final
```

I am able to mock session.execute to return me list of tuples. But after that in the code when _asdict() is called i get an execption saying tuple as no attribute _asdict(). Below is the code i have used for pytest mocking. I want to know how to mock _asdict() here.

```
mock_session.execute.return_value = [tup1,
                                     tup2]
```

Comment: The return value of the mocked execute as you have defined it is a list of tuples - tuples don't have an `_asdict` method. The mock needs to return a value that matches the interface of what one would expect from the real method, i.e. the mock needs to return something which has an `_asdict` method.

Comment: @MattClarke I am iterarting over list of tuples and then using _asdcit on tuple. But i think tuple also doesn't have _asdict attribute. Should I mock it to return namestuple instead?

Comment: Exactly right!!

Comment: I should have said originally "the mock needs to return `a list of things` which have an `_asdict` method. Sorry about that :)

Comment: I think namedtuple wont work in my case as i need to return sqlalchemy row which has _asdict operation. But i do not know how to declare it locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to mock it usinng `MagicMock()`
I am mocking the return type for `session.execute()` i.e; **CursorResult()** object like shown below.

```
CursorResult = MagicMock()
mock_session.execute.return_value = [CursorResult(tup1),
                                     CursorResult(tup2)]
CursorResult.return_value._asdict.side_effect = [tup1, tup2]
```

Comment: Nice, well done!

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comments: you can create a small class which has a `_asdict` method and use that as a stand-in for the sqlalchemy row, e.g:

```
class FakeRow:
    def _asdict(self):
        # Put whatever test data you want in the dict
        return { 'some_data': 1, 'some_more_data': 2 }
```

Then your mock would be something like:

```
mock_session.execute.return_value = [FakeRow(), FakeRow()]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt Clarke for the answer!! Just found out something almost similar using `MagicMock()` which produced similar mock effect without having explicitly to define calsses and methods for it